# Recovery folder and file?

Tags: linux, recovery

I have internal HDD with bad sectors. I was wiped the HDD to fix bad sectors but the HDD Still have problem So I replaced it with new one...

But I have forgotten to backup my Folders/Files before wipe the HDD.
Is there any way to recovery the folders and files with same name. By using Ubuntu 21.04 ?!!

Comment: when you say "wipe" what did you do precisely? also, how did you determine that the disk still had uncorrectable sectors? did you copy a bunch of data back to the disk?

Comment: I was used (wipe killdisk tools under ubuntu LiveUsb - https://www.killdisk.com/eraser.html ) to make full erase to hdd. and after erased the hdd still have same issue can not accepted to install any things linux or windows. No I did not copy any data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, you have no hope of recovering data from that drive if you have used a secure erase utility.

Just formatting the disk or deleting the partition might have allowed recovery, but this kind of tool overwrites the entire disks data. it is not recoverable. Sorry.